# Google search and integrating with my own search

Tags: search

I was wondering where i should start in trying to have a search bar that searches my database but also searches google shopping to return results.

They can be separated with a "Google search results" heading and a "This database results"

Any ideas?

I found this page, but cannot find a shopping results option:

https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Search

Answer (score 0):

This url returns a json object with search results.

Just grab an API key from google and you're on your way.

https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=KEYGOESHERE&country=US&q=SEARCH+TERMS+GO+HERE&alt=json